# Does R support switching between optimizers like STATA does?

Tags: r, matlab, mathematical-optimization

I need to implement the model show here:

http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper55/DRAfinal.pdf

The model estimation step on p.315 notes that:

"We maximize the likelihood by iterating the Marquart and
Berndt–Hall–Hall–Hausman algorithms, using numerical derivatives, optimal
stepsize, and a convergence criterion of 10^-6 for the change in the norm of the
parameter vector from one iteration to the next."

Now I know that stata supports switching between optimizers,

http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmaximize.pdf

see bottom of p2.

Is there an R package or Matlab function/s that can do the same thing?

Specifically I need to be able to switch between BHHH and Levenberg-Marquardt.

Kind Regards

Baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For R, check out the [CRAN Task View on Optimization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). Searching that page, it looks like BHHH and Marquardt are available in separate packages (`minpack.lm` and `maxLik`, respectively). You could write your own code to handle switching between them.